# Cannot cast from vector<T> to T

Tags: c++, vector, casting

I have a function that takes some arguments of type T as such:

```
constexpr inline const bool isReflex(const T x1, const T y1, const T x2, const T y2, const T x, const T y)
```

Calling this function with items form a vector yiels to an error `C2664: Cannot convert argument 1 from 'vector<T, std::allocator<_Ty>>' to 'const T'`:

```
vector<T>* v = new vector<T>; // I am not creating the vector myself, this is just for demonstration.
// The real vector is passed as const vector<T>* to a function executing the following:

if (isReflex(v[i-2], v[i-1], v[i], v[i+1], v[i+2], v[i+3]))
//           ^^^^^^ error
```

This makes little sense to me, as I am not passing the vector but rather its contents. What could be causing this behaviour?

**Edit**

Ouch.

Comment: `new vector<T>;` jesus

Comment: what's next: `new std::unique_ptr<T>`?

Comment: There is rarely (if ever) a good reason to use pointers to vectors created with new. Just use a straight vector and pass it by reference.

Comment: The vector is created in some subroutine for a mesh. Somehow the existence of the vector needs to be ensured even after the destruction of the mesh, as OpenGL relies on the data to be there. Effectively, if the vector is destroyed during a render call by destorying the mesh (i.e. due to some physics events), bad stuff will happen. There may be some way to deal with this without using a pointer to a vector, but this works well enough for the small project that I am working on.

Comment: @ionree leaking is not the correct response to dangling pointers.

Comment: Indeed. That's why I'm responsibly calling delete at the right time. I know that the solution is not ideal, and in the future I would probably also do it differently. But it is not an issue in this scenario, and means less thinking (ergo less work) for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `v` is not a vector, it is a pointer to vector. Therefore, you need a dereference operator:

```
if (isReflex((*v)[i-2], (*v)[i-1], (*v)[i], (*v)[i+1], (*v)[i+2], (*v)[i+3]))
```

The reason the error message may not look entirely clear is that `[]` operator applies to pointers as well, and behaves like a dereference operator with an offset. In other words, C++ compiler treats variable `v` as a built-in array of vectors, applies index `[i-2]` to that array, and reports an error, because the type of `v[i-2]` expression is a vector.

> The real vector is passed as `const vector<T>*` to a function

You can make a reference variable to keep the old syntax:

```
const vector<T> *pv // function parameter
const vector<T>& v = *pv;
// This will work now
if (isReflex(v[i-2], v[i-1], v[i], v[i+1], v[i+2], v[i+3])) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `[n]` operator on an `type *` object - in your case `vector<T> *`. Your compiler might be interpreting this as "give me the nth vector starting to count from this address" instead of "give me the nth element from the vector pointed to by this address".